# How to work with wordpress dévelopment server?

Tags: wordpress

I'm testing WordPress for personnal project but i would like to install locally my development WordPress website and install on my Personnal production server the final website.

In order to do that, i search a plugin or program for syncronising wordpress dévelopment with new pages, templates, and configurations inside my production wordpress.

Is there a program or plugin to do that? How is much better to work with wordpress?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Personnal production server". Although I suggest you do everything locally (some LAMP server or docker), and add URL in your website to pull/fetch new changes by GIT. Then all you have to do after finish localy is go to your URL on the production server and fetch your changes. you can use basic auth for authentication. It takes some time to write something like this, but it can be pleasant.

Answer (score 0):

There are two topics you can try:

-.By schedule copy files to production like linux CLI with crontab (every min):

```
* * * * * scp local_file remote_username@remote_ip:remote_file
```

But I don't recommend this way , and for you to easy understand.

-.By CICD, here is a blog link for you to know the concept first if you don't know this:

> https://thecodingmachine.io/continuous-delivery-on-a-dedicated-server

Briefly, you can push your project to private repo on gitlab or github, 
then make development(=development server),production(=production server) branches, the automate job will deploy to the servers if you have git push.

Here's an example main part from the link on the file .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  image: kroniak/ssh-client:3.6
  script:
    # add the server as a known host
    - mkdir ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    # add ssh key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
    # log into Docker registry
    - ssh deployer@thecodingmachine.io "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.thecodingmachine.com"
    # stop container, remove image.
    - ssh deployer@thecodingmachine.io "docker stop thecodingmachine.io_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}" || true
    - ssh deployer@thecodingmachine.io "docker rm thecodingmachine.io_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}" || true
    - ssh deployer@thecodingmachine.io "docker rmi registry.thecodingmachine.com/tcm-projects/thecodingmachine.io:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}" || true
    # start new container
    - ssh deployer@thecodingmachine.io "docker run --name thecodingmachine.io_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} --network=web -d registry.thecodingmachine.com/tcm-projects/thecodingmachine.io:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
```

It maybe hard for you to read this, but you can know there is a way which can work you need and you may take times to learn this part.

Hope it work for you.

Thanks for David Négrier sharing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is great process but i don't see volumes. All change must be done in production ?

Comment: @jeremy you mean which part on the production? if the crontab way then yes.

Comment: When i add an article on wordpress, this must be done on the production or on development wordpress ?